# Check authenticity of SAML assertion message as SP

Tags: saml, saml-2.0

We are sharing our SP metadata on public URL which also contains our public key and SSO URL (binding as well). I completely understand that public keys are meant to be freely shared between parties. But I am just trying to understand what if an unauthorised user gets access to our public key (as this is available in publicly available metadata) and knows the URL for our company's SSO (that is also available in our publicly available metadata), would they be able to authenticate themselves? How I can ensure that SAML assertion is coming from authorised source only?

Answer (score 1):

How someone having your public key would sign the assertion? They would definitely need the **private** key for this.

And this can't be just **any** private key - your SP is supposed to know the IdP's public key in advance (you don't need the whole public key, the Subject name and Thumbprint should be sufficient).

Then, when an assertion comes to the SP, it validates not only the signature itself but also, what certificate was used to sign the assertion. The SP does so by comparing the certificate information from the incoming signature to the previously stored information about the valid IdP's public key.

Answer (score 0):

The SP should have the metadata of the IdP, which includes its signing certificate(s). A SAML exchange can be secured by two way trust using the metadata of the SP and IdP. The IdP will normally sign the `AuthenticationStatement` in the `SAMLResponse` and the SP verifies the signature using the certificate(s) in the IdP metadata. Also the SP usually sends the user to the IdP for authentication so the SP is the one that starts the protocol flow.

Comment: I agree except it's the SAML assertion or SAML responses that's signed not the AuthenticationStatement. IdP-initiated SSO doesn't include the SP sending a message to the IdP. Sharing SAML metadata publicly should not present any security risks, assuming it's retrieved from the correct location.